# PHP date format to JS date format

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out

```
$datenow = date('Y-m-j H:i:s');  // 2014-08-19 17:56:13
```

I would like to generate the exact date format with JS, how I could do this?

This is how it should appears: 2014-08-19 19:57:59

Comment: What does this Format Looks like? show what you want

Comment: Straight JavaScript?  Or are you using a date formatting library?

Comment: please search before you post a question in here ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Comment: What's a JS date format? There are many formats that JavaScript understands, the simplest of them is milliseconds since epoch. How are you going to use it?

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format <-- provides a list of javascript date formatting options as well as code.  Please make an effort to provide some example code/what you've tried before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go like this :)

```
date = new Date();

dateFormated = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
date.getDay() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':'
 + date.getSeconds();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r5mdggc8/2/

There are no leading zeros, but you can add them by using condition on each "date item" like so:

```
dateItem = getDay();
if (dateItem.toString().length < 2) { 
   dateItem = '0' + dateItem;
}
```

Of course, you can make a function out of it.

Comment: I updated jsfiddle with full version including leading zeros.